# Conditional upsert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, design-patterns

I've answered this question on LinkedIn and I thought it's something useful and interesting to share. The question was:

"Suppose we have documents like `{_id: ..., data: ..., timestamp: ...}`.

Is there any way to write update criteria which will satisfy following rules:

1 If there is no documents with following `_id` then insert this document;

2 If there is exists document with following `_id` then

2.1 If new timestamp greater then stored timestamp then update `data`;

2.2 Otherwise do nothing"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution below should do the trick, you just need to ignore dup key errors. Example is given in Mongo shell:

```
> var lastUpdateTime = ISODate("2013-09-10")
> var newUpdateTime = ISODate("2013-09-12")
>
> lastUpdateTime
ISODate("2013-09-10T00:00:00Z")
> newUpdateTime
ISODate("2013-09-12T00:00:00Z")
>
> var id = new ObjectId()
> id
ObjectId("52310502f3bf4823f81e7fc9")
>
> // collection is empty, first update will do insert:
> db.testcol.update(
... {"_id" : id, "ts" : { $lt : lastUpdateTime } },
... { $set: { ts: lastUpdateTime, data: 123 } },
... { upsert: true, multi: false }
... );
>
> db.testcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52310502f3bf4823f81e7fc9"), "data" : 123, "ts" : ISODate("2013-09-10T00:00:00Z") }
>
> // try one more time to check that nothing happens (due to error):
> db.testcol.update(
... {"_id" : id, "ts" : { $lt : lastUpdateTime } },
... { $set: { ts: lastUpdateTime, data: 123 } },
... { upsert: true, multi: false }
... );
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.testcol.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('52310502f3bf4823f81e7fc9') }
>
> var tooOldToUpdate = ISODate("2013-09-09")
>
> // update does not happen because query condition does not match
> // and mongo tries to insert with the same id (and fails with dup again):
> db.testcol.update(
... {"_id" : id, "ts" : { $lt : tooOldToUpdate } },
... { $set: { ts: tooOldToUpdate, data: 999 } },
... { upsert: true, multi: false }
... );
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.testcol.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('52310502f3bf4823f81e7fc9') }
>
> // now query cond actually matches, so update rather than insert happens which works
> // as expected:
> db.testcol.update(
... {"_id" : id, "ts" : { $lt : newUpdateTime } },
... { $set: { ts: newUpdateTime, data: 999 } },
... { upsert: true, multi: false }
... );
>
> // check that everything worked:
> db.testcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52310502f3bf4823f81e7fc9"), "data" : 999, "ts" : ISODate("2013-09-12T00:00:00Z") }
>
```

The only annoying part are those errors, but they are cheap and safe.

Answer (score -1):

```
    db.collection.update({
      _id: ObjectId("<id>"))
      }, 
      {timestamp: <newTimestamp>, data: <data>}, 
      {upsert: true})
```

This operation would update an existing document if it meets the condition that it exists and that the existing timestamp is less than the newTimestamp; otherwise will insert a new document.

Comment: It does not work - there is a difference between using update operators and using field values only: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov I agree there is a difference, however, in this situation the document is completely defined by three fields: _id, timestamp and data. This works.

Comment: @Rishi you should check the question requirements and try it. It does not work. Feel free to paste an example to your answer if you think it does and you can show that.

Comment: I see that you got the requirements wrong - no duplicate insert should happen. Thus your answer is wrong. Repeat my steps in mongoshell and see that there is a difference. That's what makes this question interesting, not just a simple upsert statement.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov My previous answer did produce duplicates, thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Nowhere in that update is there any condition that states that the timestamp must be greater than the existing. This cannot possibly work. It will simply overwrite any existing timestamp, even if new is smaller.